# RatingBar changing star color without using custom images

Tags: android, ratingbar

Is there any way to change the color of star?
I don't want to use custom images to achieve it.

Comment: can you please mark the right asnwer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add these lines into on create method.

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way. Every Android version defines the default style for the rating bar and the default style uses images too. So the only thing you can do is to use your own images instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setRatingStarColor(Drawable drawable, @ColorInt int color) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color);
        } else {
            drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    }
```